# Python subprocess call in linux os not working as expected

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am trying below code in linux and trying to run linux commands in python script.

Below is the script:

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import call
a = "Team0"
b = "Team0"
c = "\'{\"runner:{\"name\": \"lacp\"}}\'"
cmd = 'nmcli con add type team con-name {} ifname {} config {}'.format(a, b, c)
print cmd
call(cmd.split(), shell=False)
```

I am getting below error.

```
nmcli con add type team con-name Team0 ifname Team0 config '{"runner:{"name": "lacp"}}'
Error: ''{"runner:{"name":' is not a valid team configuration or file name.
```

I have copy pasted above print command on linux command prompt it is working fine.

Could any one help me to fix this in my code

Comment: There is one level of quotation too much around the JSON.

Comment: Don't add quotes around your command arguments (your JSON in this case), `subprocess.call()` will do that automatically for you and in dependence of the shell it's running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1) you're splitting on a space.  So the arguments become:

```
cmd[0] = nmcli 
cmd[1] = con 
cmd[2] = add 
cmd[3] = type 
cmd[4] = team 
cmd[5] = con-name 
cmd[6] = Team0 
cmd[7] = ifname 
cmd[8] = Team0 
cmd[9] = config 
cmd[10] = '{"runner:{"name": 
cmd[11] = "lacp"}}'
```

which is why you get the Error message. Note that it's reporting everything right before the `"lacp"...`

2) Since you are setting `shell=False` the single quotes wrapping  the team config will NOT be parsed as you think.

So you can either set `shell=True` and NOT split the command or fix the parsing.

I suggest:

```
 call(cmd, shell=True)
```

as the easiest approach (note the split is missing)